# jmvfw.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform

Tags: java, dll, jmf

System:
Win 7 64 bit

JMF works on my system by starting JMstudio, it finds my drivers and starts my mic and webcam. But when I run the Netbeans code it doesn't work.

I have followed these steps on this website to install JMF on Win 7 64bit, without success:
https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2134405. I have searched in all the other answers related to this problem without any success. It should work on my 64 bit as stated in the link I pasted here.

I have installed 32 bit Java JDK,
Moved the DLL's from the JMF install folder to System32 and SysWOW64,
No errors in the code and JMF.jar is added.

Any solutions?
When I run it, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "VFW Request Thread" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: JMFSecurityManager: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Windows\System32\jmvfw.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
    at com.sun.media.JMFSecurityManager.loadLibrary(JMFSecurityManager.java:206)
    at com.sun.media.protocol.vfw.VFWCapture.<clinit>(VFWCapture.java:19)
    at com.sun.media.protocol.vfw.VFWSourceStream.doConnect(VFWSourceStream.java:241)
    at com.sun.media.protocol.vfw.VFWSourceStream.run(VFWSourceStream.java:763)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Comment: You cannot mix 32 and 64 bits applications. If you have 32-bit JVM, install 32-bit JMF as well.

Comment: I already had the 64bit JVM, but it didn't work, and on the tutorial link I pasted, it says to remove the 64bit JVM and install the 32bit JVM. JMF is originally created for the 32 bit, so it's 32 bit JMF.

Comment: Be sure you're running 32-bits JVM (run java -version in console to see)

Comment: Yes... Was running 64bit. Fixed it now, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out that my system was still running the 64 bit Java, while I installed the 32 bit. Traces of Java 64 bit were still present on my system, so I removed all traces of Java, then installed the latest Java JDK 7 on my system. Copy, pasted C:\Program Files (x86)\Java to C:\Program Files\Java, then changed the PATH and CLASSPATH to C:\Program Files\Java.
java -version in cmd worked after this and the project in Netbeans 7.4 with JMF.jar runs and captures my webcam.

Answer (score 0):

I also fell into this trap of multiple JVM's configuration 32/64 bit, make sure to match the .DLL version with JVM, i.e., 32 bit should run on 32 bit. The same applies for 64 bit.

For more information refer to eclipse forum:
https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/781808/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but please add more than just a link to another page. Please provide added-value. For instance you could say the following :  After asking a similar question saying *"I do have the 64 bit JRE and JDK installed as well"*, the PO (Joe Lee) has answered *"As stupid as this makes me sound, [...] the problem was because I wasn't pointing Eclipse to the 32 bit JRE after all"*. Please improve your answer to avoid someone down-votes it. Cheers