# Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform

Tags: java, dll

> Error loading win32com: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\bin\win32com.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform

when I using a project for send sms to phones, I got above error.
I have a machine with AMD processor. please help me by descriptive answer. thanks a lot !

Comment: You have 64 bit JDK. do `java -version` and check it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jmvfw.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19518304/jmvfw-dll-cant-load-ia-32-bit-dll-on-a-amd-64-bit-platform)

Comment: yes i have 64 bit JDK. should i  install 32 bit JDK. is that be a problem to my other projects?

Comment: actually it's work. i installed 32bit version of java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try that:

1. Download and install a 32-bit JDK.
2. Go to eclipse click on your project(Run As-> Run Configurations...) under Java Application branch.
3. Go to the JRE tab and select Alternate JRE. Click on Installed JRE button, add your 32-bit JRE and select it.