# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll

Tags: java-8, rfid, winprt

Hi I am getting this error:

> Error loading win32com: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\bin\win32com.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on
>   a AMD 64-bit platform

while running this program:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Enumeration ports = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
   System.out.println(ports.hasMoreElements());
    while (ports.hasMoreElements()) {
      CommPortIdentifier port = (CommPortIdentifier) ports.nextElement();
      String type;
      switch (port.getPortType()) {
      case CommPortIdentifier.PORT_PARALLEL:
        type = "Parallel";
        break;
      case CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL:
        type = "Serial";
        break;
      default: /// Shouldn't happen
        type = "Unknown";
        break;
      }
      System.out.println(port.getName() + ": " + type);

    }
   // System.out.println(port.getName());

  }
```

I am using java 1.8

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are probably running a 64 bit JVM.
First, check your JVM by entering this on cmd line:

```
java -version
```

If it says "64 bit", you're running 64 bit JVM incapable of loading 32 bit .dll's.
You can use a 32 bit JVM instead.

Comment: I tried on 32 bit also    java version "1.6.0_10-ea"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_10-ea-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 11.0-b09, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: But, are you running on 32 bit JVM version? See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29394163/cant-load-ia-32-bit-dll-on-a-amd-64-bit-platform